# Average velocity calculation in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

In our project, we are using VSTS for Scrum management.

I have one requirement, I need to calculate the average velocity across multiple sprints through the VSTS queries.

Please let know on how it can be done.

Comment: This is documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/team-velocity?view=vsts

Comment: @Richard, The link shared by you shows the average velocity through adding the velocity widget. I need to get the data through the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps (formerly known as VSTS) has a [handy Analytics extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics) that tracks an assortment of lagging indicators on your behalf, including but not limited to velocity, burn up/down, CFD, throughput, and cycle times. While in Public Preview, the Analytics extension is free. I use this extension and it's been great at keeping things transparent and readily useful for inspection and adaptation. I will admit the cycle time feature is a bit lacking for my purposes, but I can easily adjust in Excel based on our Kanban practices.

For your question, you're able to use this extension to find average velocity for up to 15 interations in length. Simply set your query parameters and it will track your needs automatically.